# How to assign values to a variable when reading in a CSV file?

Tags: c++, csv

```
struct LLGM{
  float Lat;
  float Long;
};

int main ()
{
 string Filename;
 int count = 0;
 string value;
 string temp;
 ifstream infile2;
 Filename = "LLMGReadingsv2.csv";
 infile2.open(Filename); 

 if(infile2.fail())
 {
    cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
    exit(1);
 }

 while(!infile2.eof())
 {
    getline(infile2, temp, ',');
    count++;
 }

 cout << count << endl;

 cout << endl;

 infile2.close();

 ifstream infile;

 infile.open(Filename);

 LLGM *points;
 points = new LLGM [count];

 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
 {
    infile >> points[i].Lat;
    infile >> points[i].Long; 

    cout << points[i].Lat;
    cout << points[i].Long;
 }

 cout << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

My question is, how can I assign the values being read in from the CSV file to individual variables?

For Example:

35.123445,-85.888762 (values in one row from the file)
I would like the first number before the comma to be Latitude, and the second value to be Longitude.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the csv file one line or thousands of lines? What kind of variable do you want to store them in?  Do you want to do something with them right away or store them for later?

Comment: the csv file that I am using in this case is quite large, and I would like to display those numbers from the example in float variables, the first one being Latitude, and the other being Longitude.

Comment: why don't you just run getline twice per loop setting the first to some sort of variable for the first item pulled from the csv, then set the second to a different variable.  Use them at that point however you would like.

Comment: hmm ok, just where I ran the getline the first time, or would it be better to just run the two getline commands in the for loop?

Comment: should be able to do it in the while loop you have now.

Comment: How would I convert the information from the getline to a float though, since it is being saved to a string?

Comment: Yeah, getline is a string function.  Look here, I found an example of basically what you are asking for.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/39e67427-4373-486d-b55c-8c96ad89c561/charstring-to-float

Comment: Are your latitude/longitude separated by new lines?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `std::ctype` facet that will interpret the comma character as the delimiter. Then you can imbue it on your file stream and insert the contents of that stream into the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>

struct my_facet : std::ctype<wchar_t>
{
    bool do_is(mask m, char_type c) const
    {
        if ((m & space) && c == L' ') {
            return false;
        }
        if ((m & space) && c == L',')
        {
            return true;
        }
        return ctype::do_is(m, c);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::wifstream infile(Filename);
    infile.imbue(std::locale(infile.getloc(), new my_facet));

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if ((infile >> points[i].Lat) && (infile >> points[i].Long)) 
        {
            std::wcout << points[i].Lat;
            std::wcout << points[i].Long;
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is a demo that uses a `stringstream` instead of a file (for demonstrating purposes only).](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ec8d70fc15bde9815b358d665bcdbc17-a59388278a81efeead67eaff53296df5)